# How can I automatically start the Xbox Gamepad driver whenever I log in?

Tags: drivers, login, sudo, autostart

I would like to start the Xbox Gamepad driver whenever I log into my computer running 18.04. 
So far, I always have to open a terminal and run

```
sudo xboxdrvr --detach-kernel-driver --daemon
```

(don't remember the args exactly; without `--daemon` the driver will block.)

It is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683384/2397253) that adding the command to `/etc/rc.local` would cause it to run on startup, but it doesn't work, regardless of using `sudo`.

Whether I suffix the command with `&` or use the `--daemon` argument, neither do the trick.

What can I do to automatically start the driver at login?

Comment: Add the command to your .bashrc, not rc.local

Comment: Does that work with `sudo`?

Comment: "but it doesn't work."  why not? it should be logged /var/log/ if it does not work. Mind that you do not need sudo in rc,local. Also: you probably need a directory in front iof xboxdrvr.

Comment: I can't find anything in the logs (except the times where I manually run the command), but I'll try without sudo.

Comment: `cron` has its own `PATH` definition, which initially is `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. Fix the `PATH` (you can specify it in `crontab`, see `man 5 crontab`, or use the absolute path to `xboxdrv`. Do you want to start it when you login, or when the system boots?

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to achieve what you want is *allowing to run **this particular command** without the need for an elevated password prompt*.

---

### Passwordless sudo command execution

To allow driver loading without prompting for a sudo password, add the following snippet to a new sudoers file include.

Example:

`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/xbox_gamepad_driver`

```
# Allow Xbox gamepad passwordless driver loading.
Cmnd_Alias XBOX_LOADER = sudo xboxdrvr --detach-kernel-driver --daemon
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: XBOX_LOADER
```

Then you can add it to your **Startup Applications** to be launched at login *(or even simply add your command to your `.profile`, which is sourced at GNOME Shell login)*.

---

### Creating startup `*.desktop` launchers

To achieve this, you can use the **Startup Applications** app *(search for it into applications menu)* and create a new entry from the GUI, or simply create a `xbox-controller-driver.desktop` file inside `.config/autostart` folder including the content below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sudo xboxdrvr --detach-kernel-driver --daemon
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Xbox Gamepad driver loader
Comment=Load Xbox Gamepad driver
```

*Note: `.desktop` files under `.config/autostart` doesn't need execution permission.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: But `.bashrc` only gets read when I open a terminal. If I had to do that every time, I might as well execute the command manually.

Comment: Based on the same premise I advise to choose `.profile` over `.bashrc`. However, a foolproof solution to ensure being launched at session login is adding it to startup applications. Answer updated.

Comment: @oarfish the desktop file can include the `.bashrc` bits you need as part of the "exec" line. it's a lazy solution but it works.

Comment: I have create the autostart file, but still nothing happens. What logs can I look into to see whether anything is (unsuccessfully) executed?

Comment: First I would verify that I can execute the command without sudo prompt, running it from a terminal. If still can, to debug you can try to redirect command output to a file to see whats happening. Maybe something like `sudo xboxdrvr --detach-kernel-driver --daemon >> driver-loading.txt` as the _Exec_ field of the desktop file can help. I updated my answer to use bash instead of sh and the desktop file to match the exact command.

Comment: First I corrected the typo everywhere (it's `xboxdrv`, not `xboxdrvr`) and then put `Exec=/bin/bash sudo xboxdrv --detach-kernel-driver --daemon >> /home/me/Desktop/driver.log` into the autostart file, but it is not being created when I log in (or maybe it is written only when the process finishes? I don't know how the redirection works in this case.)

Comment: I also still can't run the command without sudo.

Comment: In `/var/syslog/` I find `Apr 29 14:07:13 rasmus-nuc xbox-driver.desktop[1533]: /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file`. Even if I use the absolute path to `xboxdrv`

Comment: Sorry including `/bin/bash` is not required. My fault. It should include only `sudo` and `xboxdrvr --detach-kernel-driver --daemon`. Full path to `xboxdrvr` can help as you pointed but is nor mandatory if it is in your path. Also ensure you can run the same sudo command and no password is required at all. Answer updated